# IdeaMart Simulator-v2.2 is not starting up

Tags: ideamart

when executing the command to start up the [simulator](http://www.ideamart.lk/web/idea-pro/downloads/download-list/)

> ./sdp-simulator console

in Linux, the app did not start and it says. (Same problem occurred in IdeaMart Simulator-v2.0 also)

```
Running sdk-standalone...
./sdp-simulator: 1: eval: /home/majuran/Desktop/IdeaMart/Software/ideamart_developer_bundle/IdeaMart Simulator-v2.2/sdk-standalone-1.0.147/bin/./wrapper-linux-x86-32: not found
```

what shIuld i do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locate and remove the following file inside the `bin` folder.

> wrapper-linux-x86-32*